# Get values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get values from a result of my data which in a from of array . The problem is it showing blank result even if i am trying to get the value . here is my output

[image]

The code i made to get values .

```
$gallery=get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'Gallery', true); 
$successes = $gallery[0]; 
foreach($successes as $success) {
    echo "<div>Time: " . $success['imageURL'] . "</div>";
}
```

The array is returned in `$gallery` as when i echo that it says array . But when i try to echo imageURL is does not shows any results .

Comment: what happens when you do `print_r($success);` inside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: and when you `print_r($successes);` after you assign its value and before the foreach?

Comment: it echo's only one variable '1'

Comment: then don't use `[0]`.

Comment: may be its an empty array. `var_dump` and check.

Comment: It looks like you don't get what you expect from `get_post_meta`... Irrelevant to the problem, but wouldn't you want to print `$success['imagedate']` since the label says "Time"?

Comment: Well i just tried to echo anything from the array for the moment . But nothing is working even $success['imagedate'] is not working

Answer (score 0):

From the manual http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

> `$single` can either be true or false. If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string.

And you are setting it to `true`. Try setting it to `false`:

```
$gallery=get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'Gallery', false); 
$successes = $gallery[0]; 
foreach($successes as $success) {
    echo "<div>Time: " . $success['imageURL'] . "</div>";
}
```

Comment: and now when you `var_dump($gallery);` outside the loop, or `$success` inside the loop, what do you get? I suspect that the post metadata isn't what you think it is...

Comment: i get array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: That is obviously different from what you got before. Are you looking at the same post? `get_the_ID()` is supposed to be used in a loop of its own. Perhaps you are not in the context you think you are?

Comment: I have selected a ngallery from that post using advanced custom fields plugin . It was supppose to pass the images in array format . I tried getting the data as you see , but i thought i was wrong in getting it .

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your original question (or maybe ask a new one). Your problem is not with displaying array values - it is with getting the right array to be returned (I still don't understand what you did differently when you got the array you showed in your question - I believe we have established that that's not the array you get from `get_post_meta()`, even with the third parameter set to `true`. Can you hard-code the `post_ID` instead of using a function, and try again?

Answer (score 0):

try recoding and get all the keys available.

to do so

```
$gallery=get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'Gallery', false); 
$successes = $gallery[0]; 
foreach($successes as $success) {
foreach($success as $key => $s) {
echo $key;
}
}
```

i assume that your array result is wrong.